# How to change arrays into rows

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

There is a table in BigQuery that contains 2 REPEATED(arrays) type of columns, enterded_date and status.

Table in BigQuery:

[image: Table1]

Is it possible to make a query that returns rows instead?

Like this:

[image: Table2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select t.* except(entered_date, status),
  entered_date, status
from your_table t, 
t.entered_date as entered_date with offset
join t.status as status with offset
using(offset)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]